How to remove native splash icon | Flutter
I'm setting up native splash screen in flutter.
Problem :
I want to delete Flutter icon when app loads (on native level).

My AndroidManifest.xml :
  <application
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:name="${applicationName}"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
      ...

My styles.xml :
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/splash_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...


My colors.xml :
<resources>
    <color name="splash_background">#FFC0CB</color>
</resources>



Solution: You need to comment out this line in AndroidManifest.xml file.
<application
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:name="${applicationName}">
      <!-- android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"> -->

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
      ...

And after you need to reload flutter dependencies:
flutter clean
flutter pub get

